# Loop to check isNullOrEmpty then setVisibility & setText

Tags: android, null, sqlite, kotlin

My code below is working fine but I know it can be done more efficiently using a loop.

I'm checking the VAL (such as description, ingredient2, etc.) which are Strings from my SQL lite Db to see if they are Null or Empty. If true I hide them in addition to the divider views in my layout. If false I update the EditText field (such as description_text_view) with the String value from the Db.

```
    override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>, cursor:  Cursor?) {

    if (cursor == null || cursor.count < 1) {
        return
    }

    // Proceed with moving to the first row of the cursor and reading data from it
    // (This should be the only row in the cursor)
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // Find the columns of recipe attributes that we're interested in and extract out
        // the value from the Cursor for the given column index
        val name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_NAME))
        val description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION))
        val glass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_GLASS))
        val ingredient1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_INGREDIENT_1))
        val ingredient2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_INGREDIENT_2))
        val ingredient3 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_INGREDIENT_3))
        val ingredient4 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_INGREDIENT_4))
        val ingredient5 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_INGREDIENT_5))
        val ingredient6 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_INGREDIENT_6))
        val ingredient7 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_INGREDIENT_7))
        val instructions = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_INSTRUCTIONS))


        // Required fields
        // Update the views on the screen with the values from the database
        recipe_title.text = name
        glass_type.text = glass
        ingredient_text_view_1.text = ingredient1


        // Optional fields
        // If any of the following fields are empty, hide in the layout.
        // The if statements below work but there has to be a cleaner way. TODO
        if (description.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            description_text_view.visibility = View.GONE
         } else description_text_view.text = description

        if (ingredient2.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            ingredient_text_view_2.visibility = View.GONE
            divider2.visibility = View.GONE
            divider3.visibility = View.GONE
        } else ingredient_text_view_2.text = ingredient2

        if (ingredient3.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            ingredient_text_view_3.visibility = View.GONE
            divider3.visibility = View.GONE
            divider4.visibility = View.GONE
        } else ingredient_text_view_3.text = ingredient3

        if (ingredient4.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            ingredient_text_view_4.visibility = View.GONE
            divider4.visibility = View.GONE
            divider5.visibility = View.GONE
        } else ingredient_text_view_4.text = ingredient4

        if (ingredient5.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            ingredient_text_view_5.visibility = View.GONE
            divider5.visibility = View.GONE
            divider6.visibility = View.GONE
        } else ingredient_text_view_5.text = ingredient5

        if (ingredient6.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            ingredient_text_view_6.visibility = View.GONE
            divider6.visibility = View.GONE
            divider7.visibility = View.GONE
        } else ingredient_text_view_6.text = ingredient6

        if (ingredient7.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            ingredient_text_view_7.visibility = View.GONE
            divider7.visibility = View.GONE
            divider8.visibility = View.GONE
        } else ingredient_text_view_7.text = ingredient7

        if (instructions.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            instructions_title.visibility = View.GONE
            instructions_text_view.visibility = View.GONE
            divider8.visibility = View.GONE
            divider9.visibility = View.GONE
        } else instructions_text_view.text = instructions
    }
}
```

Using the suggestions from gervais.b I was able to setup a HashMap which cleans up the TextViews. Is there a way to clean up the dividers as well?

Improved code that cleans up the textviews but not the dividers.

```
 val isPopulated = HashMap<String, TextView>()
        isPopulated.put(description, description_text_view)
        isPopulated.put(ingredient2, ingredient_text_view_2)

        for ((string, textView) in isPopulated) {
            if (string.isEmpty()) {
                textView.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                textView.text = string
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your objects (`description`, `ingredient`) share a common type then you can add them to a collection and loop on it. However, you don't know which `text_view` is linked to it. So you should add them to a map.
I suppose that `description` and `ingredients` are `String`, then you can do something like

```
Map<String, TextView> viewsByString = new HashMap<>();
viewsByString.put(description, description_text_view);
viewsByString.put(ingredient2, ingredient2_text_view);
// ..
for (Entry<String, TextView> entry : viewsByString) {
   String string = entry.getKey();
   TextView view = entry.getValue();
   if ( string.isNullOrEmpty() ) {
        view.visibility = View.GONE;
    } else {
       view.text = description;
    }
}
```

However, you have to populate the map and that is not always clean. But you can still reduce your code by extracting the condition to a method:

```
void bind(String text, TextView view) {
    if ( text.isNullOrEmpty() ) {
        view.visibility = View.GONE;
    } else {
        view.text = text;
    }
}

// ...
bind(description, description_text_view);
bind(ingredient2, ingredient2_text_view);
```

Or try to use the reflection API, but that's not welcome on Android

**Edit, show composite**

This is not valid Kotlin, but I hope you can convert it.

```
class TextWithDividers {
    TextView text;
     Divider[] divs;
      // Constructor 
     setText(String text) {
         this.text.text = text
     }
     setVisibility(int v) {
       this.text.visibility = v;
       this.divs.foreach { d => d.visibility=v }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. That's an interesting idea and I'll explore that.  I also added the complete method along with some recent changes.  Hopefully it more clear as to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Regarding your whole code. I'll opt for the dedicated method solution. Or maybe an object that hold a refernce to your activity and cursor : `new Binder(this, cursor)`, `binder.set(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_NAME, recipe_title)` and `binder.setOrHide(DataEntry.COLUMN_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION, description)`

Comment: gervais.b I added some comments to my original question based on your feedback. I think we are close but the dividers are now the tricky part. Any ideas?

Comment: You can make a composite that contains the ˋTextViewˋ and the dividers. This composite will set the visibility to each of his components and the text to the ˋTextViewˋ

Comment: See my edit. But please, learn how to Google. Being able to learn and discover new things is a key for a developer